# Automatically direct logins to correct IDP depending on provided user email

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm using the Social Provider starter pack with IEF, to which I have added Microsoft Azure as a social provider. Rather than have this option appear which needs a separate click, we want to force all logins using our specific domain to use the Azure IDP, and all others to go to the default local sign up sign in.

Or if we can't achieve this, could we detect the user's domain during the local sign in and either redirect to the Azure IDP or deny the login with a message like "Please use the Azure button for this email?

I've seen various kludges which don't achieve this invisibly, but I really want to do it properly! The main reason is a compliance one - all logins using our own domain must be forced to use Azure in order to enforce MFA, which because it's a customer facing application we don't want anyone else to have to use; and we're not keen on having to use a separate MFA as it will confuse everyone (particularly me!)

It seems the route is to use custom Javascript to populate the domain_hint parameter, which might have to be the route we use, but it would be better if there was a more appropriate transformation available within B2C.

We're not currently using other social providers, but would like to be able to do this in future.

If this is possible using the sample policy https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/default-home-realm-discovery I can't work out how to achieve it, so a hint or two would be most welcome.

Default home realm discovery requires a domain_hint, which is impracticable to provide from the several websites using our B2C platform, as they don't know the user identity until the user logs in with B2C.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use that policy.

That policy inherits from B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions so just download it, change the tenant name, put your domains in "DomainLookup, have a [federation technical policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-identity-provider) for each domain and change the line:

"ClaimValueOnWhichToEnable"contoso.com

to your domain.

Ensure you have a "ClaimsProviderSelection" for each domain.